# Stand on her feet, does that phrase sounds grammatical?

Tags: sentence-meaning

There's a sentence:

> There's a good-looking woman stands on her feet...

I read it somewhere, can't tell the whole sentence, because I don't exactly remember. My question, is "stands on his feet" sounds natural? I'm not sure it's written by a native speaker, though, I can tell it's from facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence as a whole looks as if it is badly written or badly remembered. But the general phrase to "stand on one's feet," is quite common, at least in America. You normally hear it in this context:

> I've been standing on my feet all day.

The speaker might be a restaurant server or a salesperson, and the point is to explain why their feet or legs hurt so much—or, more simply, why they are unusually tired.

The duration of the standing—*all day* or whatever it is—is essential to the idiom.

Comment: I disagree. The word ***standing*** is very rarely included when pointing out that [*I've **been on** my feet all day.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+standing+on+my+feet%2Cbeen+on+my+feet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20standing%20on%20my%20feet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20on%20my%20feet%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers might be right. Certainly Ngrams is compelling evidence. I'll leave this up to show the flow of the discussion.

Comment: It's only the "quite common" bit I'm taking issue with. I'm not remotely suggesting that *I've been standing on my feet all day* is in some way "non-idiomatic" - it's just that it's not at all common when compared to the same utterance *without* the word ***standing***.

Answer (score 2):

To stand on one's own two feet means to be strong and independent. If the statement has not been remembered correctly this is a possible reading, and would mean the woman was good-looking, strong and independent, all presumably admirable qualities.

Comment: If OP's example came from a native speaker, I think it's far more likely this was the context & meaning and OP "forgot" to include idiomatically required *[her] **own two** [feet]*. As opposed to the alternative that OP came up with the idea of including ***standing*** and forgot to include some equivalent of ***all day***.